# Targeting and manipulating a chart bars and labels in a Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuetify.js

I am New to Vue and chart js, what I am trying to do is to target the chart, Add, delete and update the chart's labels and data values. 
I have a link to chartJs documentation, but where I am stuck at is in what scope in the `export default {}` block could I target the data. 
i have my chart set in a Vue component, I am also using a CLI Webpack setup.

```html
// HERE IS MY HTML
<v-flex xs12 md12 width="400px" height="400px" mt-5  >
   <canvas  id="myChart" ></canvas>
</v-flex>
```

```js
export default {
methods: {
      CreateChart(chartId, chartData) {
        const ctx =   document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ['JavaScript', 'NodeJs', 'VueJs', 'DataBase'],
            datasets: [{
              label: '# of votes',
              data: [12, 15, 23, 15],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      let data = data;
      this.CreateChart('chart', data);
    },
}
```

Now, as per ChartJs official documentation, I could have a function, I think after the `createChart()` method within the  `methods{}' scope, the function should allow me target the bars or labels for instance in the following way

```js
function addData(myChart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you want to do it by yourself but if not, have you tried vue-chartjs? Basically it makes all the integration with Vue for you, so, you just need to import it, extend it and add your data. I think it will be much easier You will find more info here
https://vue-chartjs.org/